# Безопасно ли передавать пароль методом POST ?

Tags: javascript, servlet, html

Безопасно ли передавать пароль методом POST в незашифрованном виде во время аутентификации на сайте? И если нет, то как поступают в таком случае?

ПС: извините за нубский вопрос

Comment: ssl, cram-md5(посылаем salt из БД случайное число юзеру,а  он в ответ md5(random_number.md5(salt.password)); ну и подобные алгоритмы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотря для кого и для чего. По дефолту пароли передаются в незашифрованном виде, и все, кто имеют доступ к каналу связи, могут их увидеть. Например владелец вайфай-роутера. Но, раз вы, как сами признались, нуб, то ценность паролей для вашего сайта не очень велика, так что пока можно не замарачиваться. Если же вам необходимы высокие стандарты безопасности, разумнее всего использовать SSL-шифрование. Так поступают все более-менее серьезные сайты.

Answer (score 5):

В большинстве случаев да, но если вы хотите серьёзной защиты то вам нужно использовать https авторизацию на сайте или передавать пароль в зашифрованном виде используя для этого RSA.